# How to install a package in recovery mode?

Tags: kubuntu, recovery-mode, kdm

I was using Ubuntu 11.10 and installed the KDE Desktop and I was happy with that. But I wanted to get my old login screen back [so I removed the package `kdm`](http://us.generation-nt.com/answer/need-dump-kubuntu-login-screen-help-203520172.html). When I boot my PC now, it keeps booting and nothing happens.

How can I add the `kdm` package again? I got into recovery mode, terminal and tried to execute `sudo apt-get instal kdm` but I got an error message.

> ```
> W: Not using locking for read only lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock
> E: Unable to write to /var/cache/apt/
> E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened
> ```

I'm pretty desperate now, could somebody please help me?

Comment: You can show the correct message with `LC_ALL=C sudo apt-get install kdm`. I think it could be a read-only mount problem.

Comment: @enzotib Thanks, I updated the error message above! Do you have any idea how I can fix that?

Comment: I cannot remember just now how recovery works, so my tentative would be to remount `/` in rw mode, with `mount -o remount,rw /`

Comment: Have you tried booting normally, going to tty1 with Ctrl-Alt-F1, logging in and starting the GUI with startx?

Comment: @enzotib Thank you so much, you helped me so much! :) I suggest you  make a new answer about the tty1 approach, I will accept+up vote it then.

Comment: Mounting the disk rw doesn’t matter if the network is down by default in recovery mode and you can’t install anything because the network can’t be reached.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to go to tty1 with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F1</kbd>, log in and then start the GUI with `startx`.

At that point you can reinstall the package `kdm`.

Comment: No, you can’t, because the network still doesn’t work.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to install package in recovery mode, you can first ask for repairing packages (it will mount `/` in rw mode as suggested by *enzotib*) and then, when you use the root terminal, you will be able to install new packages and avoid the error you mentioned.

Comment: Or, you won’t, since by default in recovery mode the network doesn’t work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to put @enzotib's comment here, because I missed it the first time coming here.

1. Enter "Recovery Mode" in grub
2. select, "Drop To Root Shell Prompt (read-only mode)"
3. In the shell execute the command below to re-mount `/` in *read/write mode*:

   ```
   mount -o remount,rw /
   ```

> *I was unable to login to tty2 in ubuntu 20.04 as the root password is not defined by default, and a the default user setup on system install doesn't apparently have login access here.*