# Cannot reboot after installing gnome-shell

Tags: gnome, 16.10

Today I installed gnome-shell via terminal `#apt install gnome-shell` and tried to reboot my computer, but Ubuntu did not start.
It stays in the loading screen forever and it won't let me `ctrl+alt+F2` to enter TTY2.

I don't know how to fix it, neither I know how to uninstall gnome-shell.

There are similar questions about this problem, which looks like they have not actual solution, the questioner know beforehand how to uninstall gnome in this situation.

Running Ubuntu 16.10 on a Samsung RC410

Answer (score 2):

Solved:

1. Boot in recovery mode and open root.
2. Mount `/` as read-write: `mount -o remount -rw /` as [enzotib](https://askubuntu.com/users/2647/enzotib) said in a comment [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/90377/how-to-install-a-package-in-recovery-mode).
3. Now I can uninstall gnome via apt: `apt remove gnome-shell`.
4. `reboot`.